# Reading individual xml tabs in C sharp

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to read the individual values of Lat, Long, and Alt from the xml file below using c sharp. The format for the xml is different from what I've previously worked with. I can pull out elements from the file, but I'm trying to read just the individual values for Lat, Long, Alt, etc. I haven't been able to figure out how to do that with XmlReader or LINQ.

File:

```xml
<Entry MC="11" Time="0.00" ActName="SCR_ON">
   <ActingPlat ID="1"/>
   <AgainstPos Lat="24.5399" Lon="46.7704" Alt="567"/>
</Entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get latitude do the following:

```
string xml = "<Entry MC=\"11\" Time=\"0.00\" ActName=\"SCR_ON\"><ActingPlat ID=\"1\"/><AgainstPos Lat=\"24.5399\" Lon=\"46.7704\" Alt=\"567\"/></Entry>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var latitude = doc.SelectSingleNode("//AgainstPos").Attributes["Lat"].InnerText;
```

You can get other values doing same pattern

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("AgainstPos").Select(x => new
            {
                lat = (decimal)x.Attribute("Lat"),
                lon = (decimal)x.Attribute("Lon"),
                alt = (decimal)x.Attribute("Alt")
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```